# Locking a text box from manual input

Tags: excel, vba

I have a text box in my excel worksheet that displays the value of a variable in my macro. I dont want the user to be able to manually enter any text into the textbox. I have already set the "**Locked**" property of the text box to **True**, but I can still edit the text in the text box manually. What to do?

Comment: can you be sure that none of your macros have changed the Locked to False?

Comment: It looks like you have at least one question that was successfully answered. If so, please mark them as answered by clicking the checkmarks next to them.

Answer (score 1):

Protect the Sheet and make sure the **Edit Objects** checkbox is cleared